# Description of SharePoint Online "Site Features"

Tags: sharepoint-online, features

Where can I get a detailed description of the Site Features found in SharePoint Online under the Manage Site Features setting? I need a better description than the one-liner the Microsoft typically gives.

Answer (score 0):

You could check official SharePoint Online Service Description below, I think it's helpful.

https://technet.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/sharepoint-online-service-description.aspx